# Javascript prototypal inheritance prototype function call

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Have a question about calling one prototype function in another prototype function.

for instance lets say I have a basic slider with two prototype functions.

```
function Slider() {

}

Slider.prototype.transition = function() {

}

Slider.prototype.setTargets = function() {

}
```

What is the proper way of calling the setTargets function inside of the transition function so something like this:

```
Slider.prototype.transition = function() {
   this.target.fadeOut('normal', function() {
      // call setTargets?  
      this.setTargets(); // errors when i do this
   });
}
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.target` is an jQuery Object the callback of `fadeOut` will be called with `this` as the DOMNode.

Do this instead:

```
Slider.prototype.transition = function() {
   var me = this;
   this.target.fadeOut('normal', function() {
      me.setTargets(); // <-- See me
   });
}
```

I have chosen the name <s>`that`</s> `me` for all my initialized references to `this`. I never used <s>`that`</s> `me` for DomNodes, etc. makes sence for me.

Please see comments for furture views on this point.

**EDIT:**

Acually i used `me` not `that` - Dont know what im thinking ?? !

---

**And for comment:**

```
Slider.prototype.transition = function() {
   var me = this;
   this.target.fadeOut('normal', function() {
      var domThis = this;
      me.setTargets(); // <-- See me
      setTimeout(function() {
          // Use domThis [Dom Node]
      }, 123);
   });
}
```

Or:

You can make a jQuery object of this:

```
      var $this = $(this);
      me.setTargets(); // <-- See me
      setTimeout(function() {
          // Use $this [jQuery Object]
      }, 123);
```

If you need the jQuery Object of this you can refer to: `me.target`

```
      me.setTargets(); // <-- See me
      setTimeout(function() {
          // Use me.target [jQuery Object]
      }, 123);
```

Comment: +1 but *ugh* `that`. `that` makes *no* sense. `self` maybe... :-)

Comment: some people don't like `self` either, for some good reasons.  Maybe name it `slider` like in my answer.

Comment: ran into another problem, with my references. I have a setInterval that i'm using to call the transition which screws up the this... how would I go about getting back to my reference of the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

The `fadeOut` function is not called in the context of your `slider` object.

```
Slider.prototype.transition = function() {
    var slider = this;
    this.target.fadeOut('normal', function() {
        // call setTargets?  
        slider.setTargets(); // should work now.
    });
}
```